# Why can I not open gedit with pkexec?

Tags: root, pkexec

I'm trying to run `gedit` as root, and heard that it is better to use `pkexec` over `sudo -i`.

However, when I run `pkexec gedit` I see this:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:18425): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Why does this happen, and how can I use `pkexec` with `gedit`?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. After creating the file I get the same message as "user3". What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to pkexec man:

> The environment that PROGRAM will run it, will be set to a minimal
>   known and safe environment in order to avoid injecting code through
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH or similar mechanisms. In addition the PKEXEC_UID
>   environment variable is set to the user id of the process invoking
>   pkexec. As a result, pkexec will not allow you to run X11 applications
>   as another user since the $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORITY environment
>   variables are not set. These two variables will be retained if the
>   org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui annotation on an action is
>   set to a nonempty value; this is discouraged, though, and should only
>   be used for legacy programs.

Thus to make it work - create a policy file:

`/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.policykit.pkexec.policy`

And put inside following text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>

  <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.pkexec.run-gedit">
    <description>Run Gedit</description>
    <message>Authentication is required to run Gedit</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>no</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/sbin/gedit</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">TRUE</annotate>
  </action>

</policyconfig>
```

Note, this is a policy config **only** for `gedit`, it contains path to the executable.